# closing div script in the tag of google ad manager

Tags: javascript, google-ad-manager

I am trying to make a script work inside of the tags from Google Ad Manager. The script is supposed to close the div when there are no ads to be shown

my script is this:

```
<script>
try{
parent.document.getElementById('div-gpt-ad-1407836088099-0').style.display = 'none';
}catch(e){
console.log(e)
}
</script>
```

This works fine in the console of Google Chrome but not in the web page.

I've already tried using this in the ad tag:

```
.setCollapseEmptyDiv()
```

but unfortunatelly it doesn't work if you try it with responsive tags.

Finally, the web page where is supposed to work, is the following:
https://www.perlentaucher.de/static/yl-raw.html

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the goal ? to collapse the adslot if no ad has been called ?

Comment: exactly. if is empty it should collapse

Answer (score 0):

In order to collapse empty ad divs, there are two dedicated options to define in the Google Publisher Tag :

```
//for all adslots on the page
googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs()

//for a dedicated adslot on the page
googletag.defineSlot(...).setCollapseEmptyDiv(...).addService(googletag.pubads())
```

There are several ways to configure it :

1. for all adslots in the page / collapse after the ad call if empty
2. for all adslots in the page / collapsed by default, opened if not empty
3. for a specific adslot / collapse after the ad call if empty
4. for a specific adslot / collapsed by default, opened if not empty

The following sample comes from the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/samples/collapse-empty-ad-slots) :

```
<script async src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js"></script>
<script>
      window.googletag = window.googletag || {cmd: []};
      googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        // Configure all ad slots on the page to be expanded by default, but
        // collapse slots that are unable to be filled with an ad.
        googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();

        // The above setting assumes all ad slots are likely to be filled.
        // If ad slots are not likely to be filled, pass true as a parameter as
        // shown below. In this configuration, slots will be collapsed by
        // default and expanded only if they are able to be filled.
        // googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs(true);

        // This slot will use the page-level settings configured above.
        googletag.defineSlot('/6355419/Travel', [300, 250], 'ad-slot-1')
            .setTargeting("test", "responsive")
            .addService(googletag.pubads());

        // Configure per-slot overrides.
        // This slot will be expanded by default, but collapse if it cannot be
        // filled.
        googletag.defineSlot('/6355419/Travel', [250, 200], 'ad-slot-2')
            .setTargeting("test", "responsive")
            .setCollapseEmptyDiv(true)
            .addService(googletag.pubads());

        // This slot will be expanded by default and never collapse.
        googletag.defineSlot('/6355419/Travel', [200, 150], 'ad-slot-3')
            .setTargeting("test", "responsive")
            .setCollapseEmptyDiv(false)
            .addService(googletag.pubads());

        // This slot will be collapsed by default and only expand if it can be
        // filled.
        googletag.defineSlot('/6355419/Travel', [150, 100], 'ad-slot-4')
            .setTargeting("test", "responsive")
            .setCollapseEmptyDiv(true, true)
            .addService(googletag.pubads());

        // Enable SRA and services.
        googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
        googletag.enableServices();
      });
    </script>
```

This work well, no need to manually hide the adslot yourself.